# Convert Nested IF Excel Statement to SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, t-sql

Could someone please help me convert this nested IF formula in Excel to a CASE statement (or whatever is more efficient) in SQL?:

```
=IF(B11="",IF(OR(R11="STORY.COM",R11="EXPERIENCE"),FALSE,IF(AE11="Yes",TRUE,IF(AE11="Unknown",IF(D11="",IF(E11="",FALSE,E11),D11),FALSE))),B11)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please tag your dbms.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: You cannot write sql directly in excel without using some plugg-in created for this purpose. The other option is using VBA and an OLEDB object to query your excel data, but if you are not used to use it, maybe your formula at the end results easier than what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'll scroll through left to right and put `case.. when.. then.. else..end`, you'll end up with the following:

```
case when B11 = ''
        then case when R11 = 'STORY.COM' or R11 = 'EXPERIENCE'
                then 'False'
                    else
                        case when AE11='Yes'
                            then 'True'
                        else
                            case when AE11='Unknown'
                                then case when D11=''
                                        then case when E11=''
                                            then 'False'
                                        else E11 end
                                else D11 end
                            else
                                'False' end end end
                else
                    B11 end
```